# Creating a User Profile section programmatically

Tags: development, user-profile

I'm attempting to create a new user profile section programmatically but without success. The problem is with the [Type property of the Property class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.property.type.aspx).

When I specify a value such as "section" for this, I receive the exception **Data Type is not available for section**. When I don't specify a value, I receive the exception **UserProfilePropertySettings object must have a value set for 'Type'**.

Here's the code:

```
var userProfileConfigManager = new UserProfileConfigManager(ServerContext.GetContext(site));

var propertyCollection = userProfileConfigManager.GetPropertiesWithSection();

var newProperty = propertyCollection.Create(true);
newProperty.Name = "NewSection";
newProperty.DisplayName = "NewSection";
newProperty.Type = "section";  // or not set
newProperty.IsUserEditable = false;
newProperty.Length = 0;
newProperty.DefaultPrivacy = 0;
newProperty.PrivacyPolicy = 0;
newProperty.IsSearchable = false;
newProperty.IsVisibleOnEditor = false;
newProperty.IsVisibleOnViewer = false;
newProperty.Separator = MultiValueSeparator.Unknown;

newProperty.Commit();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake - the second exception was my own due to overzealous input checking! However the code was also incorrect. It should read:

```
var userProfileConfigManager = new UserProfileConfigManager(ServerContext.GetContext(site));

var propertyCollection = userProfileConfigManager.GetPropertiesWithSection();

var newProperty = propertyCollection.Create(true);
newProperty.Name = "NewSection";
newProperty.DisplayName = "NewSection";

newProperty.Commit();
```

Comment: so did you solve it? If so the moderator would probably ask you to mark as answered ;-)

Comment: Have to wait 48 hours if answering own question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its also a good idea to set the order of the section:

```
// order being the absolute position you want to place section in property list 
propertyCollection.SetDisplayOrderBySectionName(newProperty.Name,order);
propertyCollection.CommitDisplayOrder();
```

this is usually why i do this programmatically in the first place, so i dont have to click up/down 1000 times inside the user profile property mapping list in SSP :-) – Anders Rask 0 secs ago

hth
Anders Rask